# How to decode Base64 URL safe?

Tags: java, url, encoding, base64

I need to decode a value from Base64 URL safe,  what is best approach to do that?

I didn't find any good solution over the web, and I also have no code which I built myself.

Comment: What do you mean by *URL safe*?

Comment: "base64 url safe"? Huh? base64 data is just text. it can't do anything. and whatever you decode from it can be safe as well, if you use that data properly.

Comment: Please show example input/output, and explain where you are stuck once you write some code. Stack Overflow isn't for delegating your work to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 or above, you should check [java.util.Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html). It has these two functions:

- getUrlDecoder()
  Returns a Base64.Decoder that decodes using the URL and Filename safe type base64 encoding scheme.
- getUrlEncoder()
  Returns a Base64.Encoder that encodes using the URL and Filename safe type base64 encoding scheme.

Otherwise, you may use [org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html). One of its constructors is:

- Base64(boolean urlSafe)
  Creates a Base64 codec used for decoding (all modes) and encoding in the given URL-safe mode.